# ¿Como muestro sólo los 10 primeros caracteres de un dato MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Necesito su ayuda para solucionar este problema que se me presentó. Consiste en que quiero mostrar solo los 10 primeros digitos de un dato en fila de un registro en MySQL.

**Ejemplo:**

last_session: 2019-12-14 02:44:03

**Pero quiero que quede así:**

last_session: 2019-12-14

Este es mi código PHP. Aprecio sus respuestas.

```
<p class="tdc">Último inicio (US):

<?php
 $idUsuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];
    $resultados = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT last_session FROM usuarios WHERE id = $idUsuario");
    while($consul = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados)){
        echo $consul['last_session'];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo único que necesitas es hacer uso de la función **`DATE`** para formatear la salida de la fecha, es decir quitar solo para fines de selección la parte de hora:minutos:segundos.

Entonces tu consulta debería quedar así:

```
SELECT DATE(last_session) AS last_session 
FROM usuarios 
WHERE id ......
```

Para este caso:

- Desde el gestor de bases de datos tomas solo una sección del contenido de dicha celda
- En la vista no deberás hacer uso de funciones o regex para obtener dicha longitud
- MySQL posee muchas funciones respecto a manejo de fechas y tiempos, revisa el enlace provisto

**Referencia**

- [MySQL **`DATE`** function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)

Comment: ¡¡ME FUNCIONÓ PERFECTAMENTE!! 
Gracias por tu ayuda amigo, de antemano te lo agradezco un montón.

Answer (score 0):

Que tal si pruebas con esto:

```
<p class="tdc">Último inicio (US):

<?php
 $idUsuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];
    $resultados = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT DATE_FORMAT(last_session, '%Y-%m-%d') FROM usuarios WHERE id = $idUsuario");
    while($consul = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados)){
        echo $consul['last_session'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: No amigo, no me funcionó este método. Gracias igualmemente por tu respuesta sé que a alguno sí le servirá.